# description of the function whose graph corresponds to Figure

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions, roots

Consider  f be a real continuous function , $f(0) = 0$ , and whose graph has the form shown in the figure:

a) How can a give description of the function whose graph corresponds to Figure.

b) Sketch the graph of the integral $F(x)= \int_{0}^{x} f(s) ds$  in the  corresponding space.

[image] Graphic of f

[image] Graphic of F

For a), I try to  use the roots of $f, f ', f''$, and the signs of $f, f',f''$ but I get stuck finding the roots of $f$. For b), I could not do anything, please help.

Comment: For (a) - you might want to use convexity/concavity, and note where the critical points are. With (b) - use a similar process - e.g. when $f = 0$, $F$ must have a critical point.

Comment: Try thinking what the area would be under $f$ from $0$ to $x$. This should give you a rough idea of the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's label some relevant $x$ values:

[image]

Now $F(x)=\int_0^x f(s)\,ds\implies F'(x)=f(x) \text{ and } F''(x)=f'(x)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Thus, from the graph,

$F'(x)=f(x)>0$ on $(-\infty,0)\cup(a,b)$ and so $F$ is increasing here.

$F'(x)=f(x)<0$ on $(0,a)\cup(b,\infty)$ and so $F$ is decreasing here.

Thus, $F$ has a local max at $x=0,b$ and local min at $x=a$.

$F''(x)=f'(x)>0$ on $(c,d)$ and so $F$ is concave up here.

$F''(x)=f'(x)>0$ on $(-\infty,c)\cup(d,\infty)$ and so $F$ is concave down here.

Thus, $F$ has inflection points at $x=c,d$.

Hopefully you can sketch a curve that satisfies all those conditions. Here's a (very rough!) candidate:

[image]